# Characters and symbols in HTML

Tags: html, reference, character-encoding

I am looking for a list of characters and symbols for use in HTML in PDF or image format. It could be some sort of cheat-sheet. Basically I want a reference list for use in HTML for replacing for example '`&`' with '`&amp;`'. I have found the list in http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp but if anyone can point me to pdf or image format of the list.

Regards

Comment: So you’re only looking for a list of named entities?

Comment: @Gumbo Yes, I am looking for one with entity name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Cheat-sheet](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/html-character-entities-cheat-sheet/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there one with Entity name (&amp;, &lt;, etc) along with Entity number. Regards

Answer (score 3):

There is a [complete list in the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html) but, with the exception of <, &, and " or ', you should be able to use any character directly in UTF-8 (which results in much more readable documents).

Comment: +1. This is 2009, we shouldn't still be typing out `&eacute;`.